# Ionic 2 Upgrade where to put Typings

Tags: npm, ionic2, typescript-typings

I am upgrading my app from `Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20` to `Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3` using [this guide](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-200-rc0-2016-09-28).

I am trying to figure out how to to `typings`.

I a  making use of [this](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/chats-page) which has `typings`.

In the older Ionic version (`Ionic 2.0.0-beta.20`), it had a folder called `typings`

[image]

This contained all the `typings`, however in the new version (`Ionic 2.0.0-rc.3`), there is no `typings` folder.

Where do all the typings go in the new version?

Thers is a `src/declarations.d.ts` in the new version tjat just contains the following:

```
/*
  Declaration files are how the Typescript compiler knows about the type information(or shape) of an object.
  They're what make intellisense work and make Typescript know all about your code.

  A wildcard module is declared below to allow third party libraries to be used in an app even if they don't
  provide their own type declarations.

  To learn more about using third party libraries in an Ionic app, check out the docs here:
  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/

  For more info on type definition files, check out the Typescript docs here:
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html
*/
declare module '*';
```

In my code I have the folloiwng:

```
import { Chat, Message } from 'api/models';
```

In the old version this references `typings/models.d.ts` as expected. But in the new version, this references `src/declarations.d.ts` (which has no definitions).

**UPDATE**

In RC3, where can I define the typing object?

**models.d.ts**

```
declare module 'api/models' {
  interface Chat {
    _id?: string;
    memberIds?: string[];
    title?: string;
    subTitle?: string;
    picture?: string;
    lastMessage?: Message;
    lastMessageCreatedAt?: Date;
    receiverComp?: Tracker.Computation;
    lastMessageComp?: Tracker.Computation;
  }

  interface Message {
    _id?: string;
    chatId?: string;
    senderId?: string;
    ownership?: string;
    content?: string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    changeDate?: boolean;
    readByReceiver?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typings is not used in rc-3.
All type declarations are in npm.
Installation is done as `npm install @types/package_name`
You can check node_modules/@types folder.
Links for adding type modules:
[docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/)

and

[discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-rc0-3rd-party-js-lib-with-own-custom-typescript-definition-file/65921/2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But what do I do if I have custom `typings`?  For example, I had `models.d.ts` that contained objects that used to be defined in `index.d.ts` as `/// <reference path="models.d.ts" />`.

Comment: you could try the docs I posted. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/#creating-short-hand-definition

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look

Comment: After reading the docs I am still confused and have the same question. I know in `declarations.d.ts` a definition can be defined that can be imported into your pages. However, where is the actual object defined. i.e. the object that is declared in `declarations.d.ts`?  My example would be `models.d.ts` that contains a `Chat` and `Message` object.

Comment: maybe use npm link as suggested in the discussion link in the answer. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link. I havent personally tried this. You could reply in that thread